# не получается извлечь данные с data.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

скорее всего неправильно указываю путь, но где ошибка не могу разобраться

```
class Table extends Component {
  state = {
    currency: this.props.data.currencies[0].name,
    value: 0,
    id: this.props.data.currencies.id,
    mesurSyst: ""
  };
  onChange = ({
    target: {
      value,
      dataset: { currency }
    }
  }) => {
    this.setState({
      currency,
      value
    });
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-tdd-3nttmd?file=/src/table.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В файле `data.js` у Вас отсутствовал export.
2. В файле `index.js` Вы пропсами в компонент `Table` передаете `currencies={data.currencies}` а в компоненте вы пытаетесь записать в

```
currency: this.props.data.currencies[0].name
```

Хотя у вас там нет `this.props.data` а есть `this.props.currencies` в котором лежит `data.currencies` равное

```
[
    { name: "meters", rate: 1, id: 1, mesurSyst: "met" },
    { name: "centimeters", rate: 100, id: 2, mesurSyst: "met" },
    { name: "inches", rate: 39.37, id: 3, mesurSyst: "imp" },
    { name: "foots", rate: 3.28, id: 4, mesurSyst: "imp" }
]
```

Записывайте в `state`

```
state = {
    currency: this.props.currencies[0].name,
    value: 0,
    id: this.props.currencies[0].id,
    mesurSyst: ""
  };
```

И далее по коду в методах исправьте

[Ваш пример исправленный](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-sutherland-rc4f2z?file=/src/table.jsx:90-129)